# CSS Typewriter Effect starting from right to left

Tags: css

I have a problem with my code. The flow is fine but I want the 3rd to 5th `p` tag starting to write from right to left and all I can do is from left to right.

```css
p {
  font-weight: bold;
  white-space: nowrap;
  overflow: hidden;
  width: 30em;
}

p:nth-child(1) {
  animation: type 3s steps(200, end);
}

p:nth-child(2) {
  font-weight: normal;
  animation: type2 3s steps(300, end);
}

p:nth-child(3) {
  animation: type3 5s steps(400, end);
}

p:nth-child(4) {
  animation: type4 4s steps(400, end);
}

p:nth-child(5) {
  animation: type5 4.5s steps(600, end);
}

@keyframes type {
  0% {
    width: 0;
  }
}

@keyframes type2 {
  0% {
    width: 0;
  }
  25% {
    width: 0;
  }
  50% {
    width: 100;
  }
  75% {
    width: 100;
  }
  100% {
    width: 100;
  }
}

@keyframes type3 {
  0% {
    width: 0;
  }
  25% {
    width: 0;
  }
  50% {
    width: 0;
  }
  75% {
    width: 100;
  }
  100% {
    width: 100;
  }
}

@keyframes type4 {
  0% {
    width: 0;
  }
  25% {
    width: 0;
  }
  50% {
    width: 0;
  }
  75% {
    width: 0;
  }
  100% {
    width: 100;
  }
}

@keyframes type5 {
  0% {
    width: 0;
  }
  25% {
    width: 0;
  }
  50% {
    width: 0;
  }
  75% {
    width: 0;
  }
  100% {
    width: 100;
  }
}
```

```html
<p>Opinion</p>
<p>Break</p>
<p>Thought</p>
<p>and</p>
<p>Peace</p>
```